# sdc type 2 and fk between dimension tables

Tags: data-versioning

this kind of argument has been discussed many times but I can't find a precise answer.
I have two dimension tables, say Customer and Address, that i want to model after scd type 2 pattern, with valid_from and valid_to fields, and address having a fk to customer.

The question is: when Customer changes, creating a new record and a new synthetic primary key, do I need to create a new record for the linked addresses or should I model those data differently? In my case I don't think I can put everything in the same table because the real case is a little more complex.

Another solution is to create an intermediary table, called CustomerAddress that would contain only primary key mappings, so for example if a customer changes I would create also a new record in CustomerAddress copying the old address pk and putting the new customer pk. I don't really like this solution though because it is probably hard to maintain (and in my case expose to the sqlalchemy orm)

thanks